# How do I extrapolate summation notation from a given series?

Tags: summation, power-series

I am currently working on the power series for a homework assignment. I have to find the radius of convergence for the function 
$$\frac{10}{1+64x^2}$$

By setting up the

$$\frac{1}{1+64x^2}$$

part of the expression as a derivative of

$$\frac{1}{8}arctan(8x)$$

I was able to expand the series term by term and get the correct co-efficients.

The series is:

$$\frac{10}{1+64x^2} = 10 - 640x^2 + 40960x^4 - 2621440x^6 ...$$

This series is correct, since my homework portal accepts it. In order to find the radius of convergence, I need to be able to put this series in the form of a summation notation so that I can apply the ratio tests. How do I extract this series' summation notation? How would I account for the 0 co-efficients for the terms with degree $1, 3$, and so forth (odd-terms). I know it involves an alternating series somewhere, but I am not sure how to account for the terms whose co-efficients are zero, when it comes to getting the summation form notation.

Comment: Hint: Is there something that you can multiply each term by to get the next?

Comment: Please use latex for maths text.. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: 8x? 

I will learn how to use LaTeX, I'm new to this website and haven't learned it yet. Thanks for the resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{10}{1+64x^2} &= 10 - 640x^2 + 40960x^4 - 2621440x^6 ... \\
&= 10 [1 - 64x^{2} + 4096x^{4} - 262144x^{6} ... ]\\
&= 10 [(-1)^{0}(8x)^{0} + (-1)^{1}(8x)^{2} + (-1)^{2}(8x)^{4} + ...] \\
&= 10 \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty} (-1)^{k} (8x)^{2k} \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Awesome, I was blind! The power ^2k explains so much, thanks! I thought along the lines of how to get it to cycle through the odd terms as well.